# I need to create a procedure to return values from a linked DB

Tags: sql-server

What is the syntax and steps involved to access a linked DB via a procedure?

I need to return the columns below from a table INVEST (resident on a Linked DB) using `ROWID` as input parameter.

The columns are

```
AMOUNT, TRANSACTION_ID
```

The query I currently develop throws the following error:

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "XXXX" returned message "Deferred prepare could not be completed

Comment: You mean `linked server`?

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15158017/deferred-prepare-could-not-be-completed-error-when-using-local-database-as-lin

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Deferred prepare could not be completed" error when using local database as linked server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15158017/deferred-prepare-could-not-be-completed-error-when-using-local-database-as-lin)

Comment: Yes please...

Can you please give a detail of how the procedure is gonna look like for the scenario i created.

I work on SqlDB 'A', on which I have SqlDB 'B' as a Linked Server.
I  want to create a Procedure on SqlDB A, to get data from Linked server DB 'B'.

The columns on the table 'TAccoutn' on SqlDB 'B' which I want to retrieve are TAmount and TSeq, getting data by TAccount_ID.
The Procedure is expected to return Output TAmount and TSeq.
BR,

Comment: Please find below my current query